# How to open tweet-embedded YouTube in new tab directly?

Tags: youtube, twitter

I often see tweets that have embedded YouTube videos without an actual link to them in the text contents. Example: https://twitter.com/SCSsoftware/status/996772457125240832

[image: screenshot]

My followees mostly publish high-quality videos totally unsuitable for watching in the tiny embedded frame, so I want to open them directly on the YT website. However, the only way I found to do that is to click the video which immediately starts playing, so I have to stop it, then click the title to open in a new tab, then rewind it back those 1-2 seconds I missed having to clicking here and there, not paying attention. This is extremely annoying. Is there any way to circumvent all those clicking around and just open it directly in a new tab? I tried Ctrl+click (googled this solution), but it did the same as normal click, just opened the video inside the tweet. Middle click is simply ignored.

I tried inspecting the HTML code (to try and write a userjs that would extract the link and provide it separately) but failed to find any indication of what's going to load on click. Looks like this information is hidden somewhere deep on the Twitter servers and loaded from there dynamicaly, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

The browsers I tried are Pale Moon and Vivaldi (just in case this makes a difference).

Answer (score -1):

if you are on chrome then:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>U</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>F</kbd>
3. type: **`youtube`** and click on the link

Comment: Unfortunately, a) not working for tweets posted after I loaded the page (when reading users/lists and not separate tweets); b) requires even more actions (and only saves the annoyance from autoplaying the video); c) I'm using Pale Moon, links in source are not clickable there, have to copy-paste.